# Delete folder on ftp

Tags: c#, webrequest, ftpwebrequest

Hi I want to delete a folder on my ftp
I tried this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(strPath);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.RemoveDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strUusername,strUpassword);
        using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
        }
```

Webexception was unhandled. (550)file not available

strPath = `ftp://192....../Media`
but in  Media are other folders like music, video ,....

Why doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the folder connectiong through a FTP client with the same credentials you use here ? It may be a simple access right problem

Comment: Yes the connection is good!

Comment: All you need to do is then to empty your directory before deleting it...

Comment: @Bartdude The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (eg, file not found, no access to file).

Comment: So you're telling us that your folder is empty, the credentials you use have the right to delete it, but yet it doesn't work ? Are you 100% sure about it ? Have you tested it ? Sorry to insist but simple solutions are most of the time the good ones...

Comment: no my folder is not empty

Comment: Then cfr my second remark... your directory must be empty in order to delete it. You'll need to recursively delete the content before being able to delete the directory.

Comment: Yeah I know just fixed

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error.

Try adding a forward slash to the end of media like:

strPath = ftp://192....../Media/

Still I might agree with the comments, you might need to empty the folder first.